# Purging a mailbox on an outlook client using COM object (MAPI)

Tags: powershell, outlook

```
$outlook = New-Object -ComObject Outlook.Application;
$ns = $outlook.GetNameSpace("MAPI"); 
$inbox = $ns.GetDefaultFolder($olFolderInbox);
$items = $olFolderInbox.items

foreach ($item in $items)
{
$olfolderinbox.Items | % {$_.delete()}
```

I simply need some code to run as a scheduled task to delete the inboxes/deleted items of some outlook client mailboxes periodically so as not to have a build up of aggregated data

When i run the above i get `value does not fall within the expected range, i have code to delete subfolders, theres just something not right with the above and i am struggling to see what it is. Can anyone help out with this?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See the [example here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dn189202.aspx), you miss some bits of code.

`$olFolderInbox` is `$null` in your code, and items will be found in the `$inbox.Items` collection once you initialize `$olFolderInbox` properly.

You should try this:

```
$outlook = New-Object -ComObject Outlook.Application
$namespace = $outlook.GetNameSpace("MAPI")

$olFolderInbox = [Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.OlDefaultFolders]::olFolderInbox
$inbox = $namespace.GetDefaultFolder($olFolderInbox)
for($item = $inbox.Items.Count; $item -ge 1; $item--) {
    $inbox.Items.Item($item).Delete()
}

#to empty deleted items
$olFolderTrash = [Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.OlDefaultFolders]::olFolderDeletedItems
$trash = $namespace.GetDefaultFolder($olFolderTrash)
for($item = $trash.Items.Count; $item -ge 1; $item--) {
    $trash.Items.Item($item).Delete()
}

$outlook.Quit()
```

Comment: Do not use "foreach" enumerator if you are modifying a collection. Use a down loop from Items.Count down to 1.

Comment: You are right, I've had this issue before. I'll provide another snippet.

Comment: That's great but, it still leaves data in the deleted items folder, it doesn't permanently delete! :Z

Comment: Answer udpated (simply repeat operation on the Deleted Items folder).

Comment: Thanks for your help, much appreciated.